# Sparse array support in HDF5

Tags: sparse-matrix, hdf5, sparse-array

I need to store a 512^3 array on disk in some way and I'm currently using HDF5. Since the array is sparse a lot of disk space gets wasted.

Does HDF5 provide any support for sparse array ?

Comment: [This answer][1] provides a (Python only) solution.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22589030/2858145

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chunked datasets (H5D_CHUNKED) allow sparse storage but depending on your data, the overhead may be important.

Take a typical array and try both sparse and non-sparse and then compare the file sizes, then you will see if it is really worth.

Comment: yes, [this](http://mail.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_hdfgroup.org/2010-March/002704.html) post explains how to do it (or perhaps how _not_ to do it) thanks

Answer (score 19):

One workaround is to create the dataset with a [`compression` option](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#dataset-compression). For example, in Python using [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/):

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('my.h5', 'w')
d = f.create_dataset('a', dtype='f', shape=(512, 512, 512), fillvalue=-999.,
                     compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)
d[3, 4, 5] = 6
f.close()
```

The resulting file is 4.5 KB. Without compression, this same file would be about 512 MB. That's a compression of 99.999%, because most of the data are `-999.` (or whatever `fillvalue` you want).

---

The equivalent can be achieved using the C++ HDF5 API by setting [H5::DSetCreatPropList::setDeflate](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_d_set_creat_prop_list.html#afce63c8d8c410e4a52b25b469fea1859) to 9, with an [example shown in **h5group.cpp**](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/h5group_8cpp-example.html).

Comment: Although the analysis is indeed done in python, the hdf5 file is generated in C++ so h5py is not an option. Is the same kind of compression supported natively by hdf5? I know pytables and h5py support additional compression protocols.

Comment: @andreabedini I've updated the answer with a link to a C++ example that does the same technique. I do believe that the dataset must be chunked to enable compression.

Comment: From the [HDF5 link](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage) at the start of the answer: "Chunked storage makes it possible to resize datasets, and because the data is stored in fixed-size chunks, to use compression filters." So, yep, chunking required for compression.

Comment: What does the `compression_opts` do in the above code?

Comment: @Rama 9 is the maximum compression level; see [the docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#lossless-compression-filters)

Answer (score 1):

HDF5 provides indexed storage: http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/TechNotes/RawDStorage.html

Comment: hi, Ím not really familiar with how hdf5 works internally, how can I store raw data in a hdf5 file ? does that mean I can bypass the Table datatype and write my own structures ?